# Where are the MSM files for the Visual C++ redistributable for Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, merge-module

I've been using VS 2015 for a while now and just upgraded to VS 2017 when it launched yesterday (2017-03-07). I installed with only the .NET desktop and C++ desktop workflows, without changing any other individual components.

I'm considering migrating my C++ projects to the 2017 toolchain (version "141" apparently? 2015 was "140"). I need to use the VC merge modules for my installer, so I looked in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules` folder, but that folder only contains `VC140` MSMs where I was expecting to also see `VC141` MSMs added by the installation of 2017.

Where are the MSM files for the 2017 VC runtime?

I briefly (very briefly) considered the possibility that because 2017's VC number looks like a semver minor bump from 2015's VC number, the 2015 MSMs might suffice for the 2017 runtime, but... that seems unlikely.

Comment: I have them in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Redist\MSVC\ subdirectories.  Having "Enterprise" in the path name was a remarkably dumb idea, tweak to match your edition name.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant, I found them there. If you want to post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: It is such a drastically dumb idea, I don't want to have anything to do with supporting it.  SO users would vote such a post as unhelpful.  Please complete the Q+A yourself, you can vote Obsolete on my comment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## As of Visual Studio 2017 RTM ...

I found the MSM files I was looking for at the following path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.10.25008\MergeModules
```

The edition name is embedded in this path, which is a little unfortunate. Replace that path element according to the edition you've actually installed.

Also, the numeric path element after `MSVC` may be different depending on what Visual Studio update you currently have installed.

The full list of MSM files I found at that location:

```
Microsoft_VC150_CRT_x64.msm
Microsoft_VC150_CRT_x86.msm
Microsoft_VC150_CXXAMP_x64.msm
Microsoft_VC150_CXXAMP_x86.msm
Microsoft_VC150_DebugCRT_x64.msm
Microsoft_VC150_DebugCRT_x86.msm
Microsoft_VC150_DebugCXXAMP_x64.msm
Microsoft_VC150_DebugCXXAMP_x86.msm
Microsoft_VC150_DebugOpenMP_x64.msm
Microsoft_VC150_DebugOpenMP_x86.msm
Microsoft_VC150_OpenMP_x64.msm
Microsoft_VC150_OpenMP_x86.msm
```

## As of Visual Studio 2017 v15.3.1 ...

Apparently a `150` version string in the merge module file names is not what MS intended. See the release notes [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#a-idctoolsetlibs15a-visual-c-toolset-and-libraries). The updated merge module file names use a `141` version string instead, to match the toolset version 14.1x.

Comment: There is also an update `VC\Redist\MSVC\14.10.25017` which only updated MFC modules.  Didn't include vcredist.exe for me, have to download seperately, X86/X64, no update for ARM.