# Silent installation msi

Tags: installshield

0x80070652 - when installing VS 2012 C++ redistributables.
Hi All,

I have a weird issue for the last few days now, i've been looking for a solution in the forums, google etc.
So far, couldn't find a similar problem:

Scenario:

1. I have an "Basic MSI" project that deploy our company product.
2. everything worked OK till i needed to add installation of VS 2012 C++ redistributables.
3. i'm using the installscript to initiate a command line for installing it quietly - 'vcredist_x64.exe /q'.
4. if the custom action is being added to the execute sequance, the following error is coming from the "VS 2012 C++ redistributables. -
   ERROR 0X80070652: ERROR_INSTALL_ALREADY_RUNNING.This error is due to Another installation is already in progress. Complete that installation before proceeding with this install.
5. if running it manually, regardless to the IS installation, everything is working perfectly.
6. Also, when the custom action is on the UI sequance - works great. - i cannot leave it on the UI sequance, since our product is being deployed quietly along with our product client.
7. I've been trying to change into a different project type - "installscript MSI"... Same error.

Please advise, thanks for any inputs.

Answer (score 0):

***Short Answer***: You can't run this executable from inside your MSI for [technical reasons](https://serverfault.com/a/274675/20599), you should run them in sequence instead. First the executable, then your MSI (batch file or manually). Or you should make an executable that runs them in sequence (WiX Bundle for example).

---

***VCRedist***: The VS 2012 C++ redistributable **`vcredist_x64.exe`** is a WiX Bundle with a couple of MSI files inside. You are not allowed to run embedded / nested MSI files concurrently with the main MSI installation. [Simple explanation here](https://serverfault.com/a/274675/20599). Inline explanation: This is because MSI files install as a transaction that is supposed to be possible to roll back. Hence the file installation sequence locks the system to prevent other MSI files installing when one is already in progress.

***Extract***: You can extract a WiX bundle using the WiX toolkit's dark.exe: `dark.exe /x D:\VCRedist vcredist_x64.exe`. WiX toolkit must be installed and dark.exe must be in the path or you must specify its full path.

***Setup.exe***: The solution is to run the MSI files in sequence inside a setup.exe bundle created with WiX, [Installshield](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64135249/129130) (see link for sample screenshot - [more on suite projects here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52470977/129130)), Advanced Installer or a similar setup creation tool. Another approach is to simply deliver the runtime next to your installer and install them in sequence with a batch file or even by instructing the user to do so.

***Merge Modules***: Most VCRedist versions have merge modules that you can use to install the runtime (as opposed to setup executables). [WiX sample](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_vcredist.html). These are merged into your own MSI at build time and hence feature no nested MSI processes. [There are some issues with merge modules and recent VCRedist versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51421050/wix-merge-c-runtime/51423249#51423249).

---

***Links:***

- [The latest supported Visual C++ downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)
- [Detect VC runtime presence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53639128/129130)
- [Similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52121996/129130)

Comment: if the custom action is being added to the execute sequance, the following error is coming from the "VS 2012 C++ redistributables. - ERROR 0X80070652: ERROR_INSTALL_ALREADY_RUNNING.This error is due to Another installation is already in progress. Complete that installation before proceeding with this install.

In custom action what i have to choose it in execute sequence, to solve above error.

Comment: You can't run this executable from inside your MSI for technical reasons, you should run them in sequence instead. First the executable, then your MSI (batch file or manually). Or you should make an executable that runs them in sequence (WiX Bundle for example).

How to  run them in sequence instead

Comment: As stated in the answer Installshield has a "Suite Project" feature which allows you to make an executable that will install MSI files, EXE files and other types of files in sequence. See the screenshot linked above. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64135249/129130). WiX has the Burn features for the same purpose and Advanced Installer has the prerequisistes view and other features.

Comment: We are using install shield basic MSI roject in this how and where we have to customized Vc++.exe during silent installtion of msi. i could see above answers for suite roject.

Comment: My simle question is that how to configure or customized  VC++.exe in basic msi roject in Installshiled 2o15,during silent installtion of msi.

Comment: In installshield Sequencing a Custom Action that Launches an .exe File during silent installation of msi

Comment: Could you update the project to use a newer version of the VCRuntime and add the merge modules to your project for that runtime version? They should be available and work unless you do some UWP stuff (Universal Windows Platform). I don't recall if 2012 had merge modules. If it did, they are probably outdated by now installing older files without the latest security fixes. There is also static linking (not good security-wise), some VCRuntime versions allow you to copy runtime files locally - just as bad. You could document this well for silent installation and install vcredist_x64.exe via GUI?

Comment: Another question
How to check the ability to sign the installer and how to proceed ?
To avoid the message we have now when we install/upgrade the Server or Client ?

Comment: Maybe try these two answer for a start: [Digital Signing & SmartScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50414337/129130) and [Digital Signing and UAC prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51209972/129130). Also check [Advanced Installer Signing FAQ](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/faq-digital-signature.html) and [Installshield Signing Documentation](https://docs.revenera.com/installshield26helplib/helplibrary/IHelpReleaseDigitalSignature.htm).

Comment: Do you have any install shield demo project tutorial video to sign the installer.if you share it will be very helpful  for our project.Thanks.

Comment: If I install main release MSI, will the "patches.msp" (If multiple patches present) automatically trigger and update,How?And share some reference link.